# OutOfMemory error for 2D arraylist of double values of row 16k and col 23k?

Tags: java, arraylist, memory-management

I am taking input a 2D array  whose row and column are 16,000 and 23,000 respectively from a file . Then I am storing these data in the following data structure :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> constraint ;
```

The size of each Double object is 16 bytes . So there are 23k*16k objects . TOtal size of memory is 16,000*23,000*16/1024/1024/1024 = 5.98 GB .

The total Ram of my pc is 8 GB . I cant give 6 GB to it .If I give then my pc hangs . I have heard that in Machine learning the programmer has to deal with a lot of data . How can they do them ? I wonder .

[I have read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27759877/6379197) . But I have to get all data and then I have to process this data . Please give me any idea to handle this problem .

Comment: What are you doing with the data? For what purpose are you trying to load it?

Comment: I am working with a new algorithm of linear programming .

Comment: First of all: when you do intensive number crunching, then consider using a single flat `double[] numbers` array instead of collection types. And beyond that: most likely you will have to log into your specific problem and see if there are ways to solve it *without* having all data in memory the whole time. In other words: you probably have to step back and rethink your complete problem. That is nothing we could help with.

Comment: A way to avoid this is to not try and load the data all at once. But since you haven't specified what you are _doing_ with the data, it's impossible to say what you could do differently.

Comment: Or in other words: if your machine doesn't support solving this problem, then look for other problems or get another machine.

Comment: It will be easier to answer the question if you specify in more detail how you intend to manipulate the data, and how sparse it is -- that is, how many of the data elements are non-zero. Data can usually be compressed, but a method of compression has to be chosen that matches the way the data will be manipulated. If your data is very sparse, then there are open-source libraries specifically for storing and manipulating data of that kind. However, they tend to assume that you will be doing conventional linear algebra stuff, like multiplying matrices.

Comment: Some years ago I had a similar problem (dealing with sparse large term-document matrices). I had tried [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/), [jBlas](http://jblas.org/) and finally used [Matlab Runtime Compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr.html) in order to run the matrix multiplications with matlab. My main program was written in java.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory calculations are wrong.

This part is correct: the memory needed to represent the `Double` values is 16 x 16,000 x 23,000 is ~5.9GB

But then there are 16,000 x `ArrrayList<Double>` instances, each of them containing 23,000 references to `Double` objects.  Assuming 8 byte addresses, that is going to occupy *at least* a further ~2.9GB ... and probably more depending on how you assembled the array lists.

(If you create `ArrayList` objects with the default size and "grow them" by appending elements one at a time, then the `ArrayList` strategy for reallocating the backing array is going to result in unused space at the ends of the arrays.  The amount is likely to be significant.)

So the actual memory utilization is going to be 9GB ... or more.

Then add the fact that filling a heap to 100% is not viable ... so you would probably need a 16GB RAM machine for the calculation.  (Maybe less with oops compression ... but still not a 6GB heap which is the max size that seems to work for you.)

---

So how *can* you represent a large array of double precision floating point values

1. Use `double` values not `Double` objects.
2. Use arrays not `ArrayList` objects.
3. To minimize the memory ... use a 1D array not a 2D array.  (In Java, a `double[][]` is actually an array of arrays.)

My rough calculation is that a `double[16000][23000]` will occupy ~2.9GB.

(Note that oops would make little difference with this data structure ... but you are well below your limit anyhow, so that won't matter.)

---

Are there other ways?  Possibly!  But it depends on your algorithm's "locality" characteristics.

For example, you could use off-heap memory (or a memory-mapped file) to hold the array.  Now you don't have to worry about what happens to performance when the GC runs, and you can use the theoretical minimum amount of memory to hold the required number of `double` values.  However if your access patterns are "wrong", then your algorithm could lead to virtual memory thrashing.

The solution to that might be to restructure the algorithm to *optimize* the way it accesses the array.  But that may not be viable.

---

Finally, it must be recognized that some algorithms simply require huge amounts of physical memory; i.e. big expensive hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could be a good idea, but you can read your data directly from a file with RandomAccessFile.

For example, I store an array of double data in a file this way:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("array.dat"));
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    out.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[8]).putDouble(i).array());
out.close();
```

Then when I want to access data

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(new File("array.dat"), "r");
raf.seek(5000 * 8); // Seek the value at the index 5000
System.out.println(raf.readDouble()); // Print 5000.0
```

Of course if you do that, your computation will be much more slower than using a simple array of double because of disk access, but you won't load data in the memory. As a try, computing a simple mean value on 1 million doubles take 5 ms with an array, and 9000 ms with that method, not optimized at all!

Comment: Splitting it into chunks would be better. For each x, save the previous (x) rows to a file (%d.dat). Discard the data in memory and save the next x rows to a new file. Then loading would be simply getting the entire file into an array. Then doing `array[5000]`. There are some slow periods (save/load) but loading from the array would be much faster. This way works too, I want to specify that, but as you said yourself it is slower.